# Multiple XMLHttpRequests - retrieving data from multiple responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code that appends

```js
var URL = 'mysite.com/get_counts?type='

if ($('.logo1').hasClass('active') === true) {
  var logo1 = '&source_list[]=1'
  URL = URL + logo1
} else {
  var logo1 = ''
  URL = URL + logo1
}

if ($('.logo2').hasClass('active') === true) {
  var logo1 = '&source_list[]=2'
  URL = URL + logo1
} else {
  var logo1 = ''
  URL = URL + logo1
}

if ($('.logo3').hasClass('active') === true) {
  var logo1 = '&source_list[]=A&source_list[]=B'
  count += 1;
  URL = URL + logo1
} else {
  var logo1 = ''
  URL = URL + logo1
}

var API = new XMLHttpRequest();
API.open('GET', URL);
API.onload = function() {
    let dict_exclude, o = JSON.parse(API.responseText);
    dict_exclude = {
      total_either_sources: true,
      total_all_sources: true
    };
```

If logo1 is active, and logo3 is active, I receive JSON like this:

```
{"total_1": 10, "total_A": 8, "total_B": 2,"total_either_sources": 20, "total_all_sources": 1}
```

My problem lies in the fact that I need the "total either sources" figure, but I need the "total all sources" to be derived like so:

```
{"total_1": 10, "total_A": 8, "total_B": 2,"total_either_sources": 20, "total_all_sources": 1}

{"total_1": 10, "total_A": 8,"total_either_sources": 12, "total_all_sources": 5}

{"total_1": 10, "total_B": 2,"total_either_sources": 12, "total_all_sources": 2}
```

So I can add those two responses and get "total_all_sources": 7. This figure is a bit difficult to fully comprehend because it's not present in this example. But it's an abstract figure representing another number that cannot be gained from the original query and how the application is designed.

But I can't figure out how to get this done. I need to run three different XML Requests.

Any help?

Comment: `=== true` is not needed on a boolean

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking...